# Ajax content invisible in firebugs, and unable to use hover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I used ajax call to generate content when user input query, it works well until I try to use jquery's hover function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".numbers").hover(function(){
    $(".fullUnits").fadeIn(80);
    $(".units").fadeOut(0);    
  }, function(){
    $(".fullUnits").fadeOut(0);
    $(".units").fadeIn(80);
  });
});
```

the code above is actually correct, it doesn't work because .number is invisible to browser. this is how it looks in firebugs.grayed out which means not visible. so you cannot hover on it.(sorry, I cannot post image now)

[Screenshot http://converteveryunit.com/firebug.png](http://converteveryunit.com/firebug.png)

the following code is the ajax code, which is used to generate content

```
function showHint()
{
  var str = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
  if (str.length==0)
  { 
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  var query = "gethint.php?q="+str;
  if (document.getElementById("m2u").checked) 
  {
    query = query + "&mode=m2u";
  }
  else if (document.getElementById("u2m").checked) 
  {
    query = query + "&mode=u2m";
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET",query,true);
  xmlhttp.send();

}
```

in case you need other code, the demo is at [converteveryunit.com](http://converteveryunit.com)

Answer (score 0):

you must bind your hover event after the content is onloaed

Comment: but the content is always grayed out in firebugs. does that matter?